# select scope_identity() using createSQLQuery in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I am forced to use `createSQLQuery` to insert values into tables with an Identity column (the first column and the primary key) using hibernate. Using hibernate classes are not an option since the tables are created on the fly for each customer that is added to the system. I have run the query and it successfully inserts into the table. I then execute a "select scope_identity()" and it always returns null. "select @@Identity" works but that is not guaranteed to be the correct one. I have also tried to append "select scope_identity()" to the insert query. Then I tried `query.list()` and `query.uniqueResult()` both of which throw the hibernate exception of "No Results ..."

```
    Session session = DatabaseEngine.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    String queryString = "insert into table1 (dataid) values (1)"
    SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(insertQueryString); 
    query.executeUpdate();
    query = session.createSQLQuery("select scope_identity()"); 
    BigDecimal entryID = (BigDecimal)query.uniqueResult();
```

The simple example table is defined as follows:

```
    "CREATE TABLE table1 (EntryID int identity(1,1) NOT NULL," +
    "DataID int default 0  NOT NULL, " +
    "PRIMARY KEY (EntryID))";
```

Is there a way I am missing to use scope_identity() with `createSQLQuery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the [`SQLServerDialect`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.10.Final/org/hibernate/dialect/SQLServerDialect.java#SQLServerDialect) class used by Hibernate uses the same "scope_identity()" too.

The reason why it's not working is because you need to execute those in the same statement or stored procedure.
If you execute the scope_identity() call in a separate statement, SQL Server will not be able to give you last inserted identity value.

You cannot do it with the `SQLQuery`, even Hibernate uses JDBC to accomplish this task. I wrote a test on GitHub to emulate this and it works like this:

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
final AtomicLong resultHolder = new AtomicLong();
session.doWork(connection -> {
    try(PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO post VALUES (?) select scope_identity() ") ) {
        statement.setString(1, "abc");
        if ( !statement.execute() ) {
            while ( !statement.getMoreResults() && statement.getUpdateCount() != -1 ) {
                // do nothing until we hit the resultset
            }
        }
        try (ResultSet rs = statement.getResultSet()) {
            if(rs.next()) {
                resultHolder.set(rs.getLong(1));
            }
        }
    }
});
assertNotNull(resultHolder.get());
```

The code uses Java 8 lambdas instead of anonymous classes, but you can easily port it to Java 1.7 too.